# Angular 8 - dependent dropdown for each row in a table created by ngFor not working

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a table of each row having dependent drop downs. If I change in one row it changes all the other dropdowns in other rows.

I attached my sample code below,

component.ts code,

```
'''
selectedCountry: String = "--Choose Country--"; 
Countries: Array<any> = [
        { name: 'Germany', states: [ {name: 'A', cities: ['Duesseldorf', 'Leinfelden-Echterdingen', 'Eschborn']} ] },
        { name: 'Spain', states: [ {name: 'B', cities: ['Barcelona']} ] },
        { name: 'USA', states: [ {name: 'C', cities: ['Downers Grove']} ] },
        { name: 'Mexico', states: [ {name: 'D', cities: ['Puebla']} ] },
        { name: 'India', states: [ {name: 'E', cities: ['Delhi', 'Kolkata', 'Mumbai', 'Bangalore']} ] },
    ];
    states: Array<any>;
    cities: Array<any>;
    changeCountry(country) {
        this.states = this.Countries.find(cntry => cntry.name == country).states;
    }
    changeState(state) {
        this.cities = this.Countries.find(cntry => cntry.name == this.selectedCountry).states.find(stat => stat.name == state).cities;
    }
'''
```

HTML code below,

```
<tr  *ngFor="let ticket of t.controls; let i = index" [formGroup]="ticket" class="form-row">
          <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
          <td><input formControlName="mastid"  ></td> 
          <td>
            <select placeholder="Country" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" (change)="changeCountry($event.target.value)" formControlName="mettype" class="form-control">
              <option>--Choose Country--</option>
              <option *ngFor="let country of Countries">{{country.name}}</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select placeholder="State" (change)="changeState($event.target.value)" formControlName="datatype" class="form-control">
              <option>--Choose State--</option>
              <option *ngFor="let state of states">{{state.name}}</option>
            </select>
          </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to define ngModel for each dropdown **[(ngModel)]="selectedCountry[i]"**

are define **selectedCountry=[];** in component

```
  <tr  *ngFor="let ticket of t.controls; let i = index" [formGroup]="ticket" class="form-row">
      <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
      <td><input formControlName="mastid"  ></td> 
      <td>
        <select placeholder="Country" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry[i]" (change)="changeCountry($event.target.value)" formControlName="mettype" class="form-control">
          <option>--Choose Country--</option>
          <option *ngFor="let country of Countries">{{country.name}}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select placeholder="State" (change)="changeState($event.target.value)" formControlName="datatype[i]" class="form-control">
          <option>--Choose State--</option>
          <option *ngFor="let state of states">{{state.name}}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
```

Comment: Thanks Yadav. I tired this [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry[i]". But in state column it changed for all rows. Something I need to tweek in component.ts. I'm a newbie, so please don't mind.

Comment: same thing with formControlName=datatype[i] you need to defind formcontrol for all satates

Comment: can you create stackblitz for this

Comment: this is working please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xkvp22?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Hi Palak, Thank you very much. It was very helpful. When I tried to add cities, it went wrong. Also i can see that in console that datatype is empty even after selecting. i guess its due formControlName="datatype[i]". i again updated the code with your changes and I added cities option to the ciites column.stackblitz.com/edit/angular-326sky. I'm also getting some errors. Can you please help me to fix this.

Comment: Please check updated code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xkvp22?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

make a filter in external file like - mycustomfilter.ts

**mycustomfilter.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'myFilter ',
    pure: false
})
export class myCustomFilter implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], field : string, value): any[] {
    if (!items) return [];
    if (!value || value.length === 0) return items;
    return items.filter(it =>
    it[field] === value);
  }
}
```

**declarations** in app module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App, myCustomFilter],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

**athlete.component.ts**

```
CountryList: Array<any> = [
    { name: 'Bangladesh', id:1 },
    { name: 'Spain', id:2 },
    { name: 'USA', id:3 },
    { name: 'India', id:4  },
];

CityList: Array<any> =[
         {id:1,name:'Dhaka',CountryID:1},
         {id:2,name:'Rajshahi',CountryID:1},
         {id:3,name:'Barcelona',CountryID:2},
         {id:4,name:'New York',CountryID:3},
         {id:4,name:'Kolkata',CountryID:4},
         
    ];
```

**athlete.component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let athlete of o.controls; let i = index" [formGroup]="athlete" class="form-row">
              
<td>
<select class="form-control" formControlName="CountryID">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option *ngFor="let s of CountryList" [ngValue]="s.id">{{s.name}}</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select class="form-control" formControlName="CityID">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option *ngFor="let s of CityList| myFilter : 'CountryID' : athlete.value.CountryID" [ngValue]="s.id">{{s.name}}</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

hope this will work for you